# Visual Studio nullability ref errors show as warnings if defined in Directory.Build.props

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nullability

This might just be a temporary VS bug, but I wanted to see if anyone had any fixes or if there was perhaps a VS setting I was missing.

If I define nullability errors:

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
<WarningsAsErrors>nullable</WarningsAsErrors>
```

And I do so within a `.csproj`, it works out as one would expect:
[image: Nullability Errors Showing]

However, if the properties are defined in a `Directory.Build.props` file, which applies to a solution en-masse, they do not show as errors anymore:
[image: No Errors Showing]

It still blocks compilation, and you can still see the error in the raw text output.. but the red squiggle doesn't show (just green) and more importantly, the Error List pane is empty.

Does anyone know why this is, or how to fix it?  I would like to have nullability errors defined en-masse via the `Directory.Build.props`, but it's unusable in its current state.

Comment: Did you restart the VS after adding a `Directory.Build.props`? Full rebuild/clean of solution might help, as well as deleting a `.vs` folder

Comment: @jwdonahue do you have some sort of reference for that statement? They don't "implement support" for props/targets files on a per-property basis. Everything just "trickles down". And you can definitely set both properties OP is after in the props file... Its exactly what I do

Comment: Silly question, but the props file isn't in the same folder as the project is it (as opposed to at least the solution level/directory above project)? I've seen unexpected behavior if you try that

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, it's just been my experience that not everything works from the directory.build.props level (I really wish they did).  I recall reading some documentation on how some tags just aren't meaningful at different scopes, but I don't have a reference on hand.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, I retract the statement. The fact that I've found some things just don't work, doesn't mean they shouldn't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Actually**, [automatic msbuild import function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) has two ways: `Directory.Build.props` and `Directory.Build.targets`.

**In your side**, you should use `Directory.Build.targets` rather than `Directory.Build.props`.

As the document said, `Directory.Build.props` is imported at the top of the `csproj` file. So it should be used to define global msbuild properties that used on the global environment. And the properties defined on it can be overwritten by the `csproj` file.

Your situation is that the `WarningsAsErrors` is overwritten by the system default value `none` from `csproj` file. Although the value is not shown on the csproj file, it actually shows as `none` by default. When you create a new project without any changes, it always shows as a warning.

**Solution**

**Therefore**, you should rename the file as `Directory.Build.targets` and it always is used to overwrite any operation properties like `WarningsAsErrors`.

Mostly like [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936714/why-does-msbuild-fails-to-find-my-constant-in-directory-build-props/65949594#65949594).

Comment: Nullable=enable can be set in a props file and works just fine. On the OP I overlooked WarningsAsErrors and misread it as TreatWarningsAsErrors, the latter of which can also be set in a props file just fine