# foreach design idea

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does .NET foreach loop throw NullRefException when collection is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088147/why-does-net-foreach-loop-throw-nullrefexception-when-collection-is-null)

foreach iterator throws the exception if the target collection is null.

Example:

```
List<string> names = null;
foreach(var name in names) { /* throws exception */ }
```

What is the design idea behind it. Isn't it handy to not iterate through the loop instead .NET Framework throwing exception?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, a null collection indicates that a collection is not valid. I would expect an empty collection to not iterate, but a null collection to exception as I was expecting a valid collection.

[Why does .NET foreach loop throw NullRefException when collection is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3088147/1232571)

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no idea behind. As you know foreach was added much later then Enumerator and foreach is built on it(*).

(*)
`foreach` is somewhat equivalent to:

```
var enumerator = someList.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    //do something with enumerator.Current
}
```

You cannot run `GetEnumerator` on something which is null.

Comment: In which version of C# did you think `foreach` was introduced?

Comment: In version 2.0 you got possibility to write foreach for your own collections.

Comment: I just found this confirming this: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/What-s-New-in-the-NET-Framework-2-0.id-290323.html See: Iterators.

Comment: No, in version 1.0 you could write collections that could be used with foreach.  The foreach statement is "duck typed"; the collection type must have a `GetEnumerator()` method and the type returned by the GetEnumerator method must have a `bool MoveNext()` method and a `Current` property.

Comment: You're welcome :) See this blog post from Eric Lippert for a discussion: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx