# Using Linq to objects, how to create an empty dictionary of <string, string> easily?

Tags: c#, linq

To create an empty sequence one uses the following

```
var empty = Enumerable.Empty<string> ();
```

Is there an equivalent for creating an empty dictionary as easily as this?

Comment: What does it have to do with Linq?

Comment: Sometimes google helps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: Expected more pro question when rep ~2000. You are by using LINQ shooting a fly with cannon. Just use plain `new Dictionary<string, string>();`

Comment: seems like a perfectly good question to me. There is string.empty and Enumerable.Empty why not Dictionary<string,string>.Empty. I can guess at implementation issues but its a perfectly reasonable concept;

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No there is no equivalent...

The purpose of `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` is to return a "cached" instance of an empty array. So you can avoid the overhead of creating a new array (`return new T[0];`).

You cannot translate this to a non-readonly structure like a `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` or `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` since the returned instance might be modified later and would therefore invalidate the purpose...

Comment: Yes, there is: `ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Empty`

Comment: As @stefan said - there isn't. However to achieve minimal allocations you can create your own static empty dictionary, e.x.: `private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> EmptyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()` or even an extension to a static (actually cached overtime) single allocation

Answer (score 55):

Back to year 2019, there is a way to achieve this, using:

```
ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Empty
```

More info can be found here (last couple of posts): https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25023

Comment: Is it limited to some newer versions? I can't seem to find it nor VS nor ReSharper knows about it? Also, is there another alternative otherwise?

Comment: I manually found a port for .NET 4.0 on Nugget but sadly found out that `foo?.ToDictionary(…) ?? ImmutableDictionary<Foo, Bar>.Empty` does not compile. :(

Comment: Not sure how I never saw this comment. The issue you have is obvious. `ToDictionary()` returns `Dictionary<K,V>`, while `ImmutableDictionary<K,V>.Empty` returns `ImmutableDictionary<K,V>`. Although both types implement similar interfaces (e.g. `IDictionary<K,V>`), the `??` operator doesn't know which type to use for the expression result. For example `var a = foo?.ToDictinary<K,V>() ?? ImmutableDictionary<K,V>.Empty` is ambiguous, but if you write `IDictionary<K,V> a` instead of `var a` the compiler will know what to cast the result of `??` operator into.

Comment: As @Stefan mentions below the key is whether you need a `Dictionary<K,V>` or an `IReadOnlyDictionary<K,V>`.  If you're talking about an immutable object then `ImmutableDictionary<K,V>.Empty` is what you're after.  If you need a mutable dictionary than you'll need to allocate a new one each time because code could add items to the dictionary and you wouldn't want this to happen with a shared object.

Comment: I had to add (for a dot-net-core code base) this package ref PackageReference Include="System.Collections.Immutable" Version="a.b.c"     1.7.0 when I wrote this comment.

Answer (score 13):

What's wrong with `new Dictionary<string, string>()`?

Comment: An empty Dictionary is mutable and might consume memory as you instanciate it multiple times. He might want a reference to a readonly empty IDictionary<string, string>.

Comment: @zx485, immutable empty data-structures are common -when you deal with immutable types- even this question mentions `Enumerable.Empty`. You can also take a look at the null object pattern but if you really want to know more, you can post a dedicated question here ;)

Comment: The reason for the existence of `.Empty` constructs in c# is to provide a convenient way of acquiring a static, cached, immutable instance of an empty representation of an object, which can be used in places where such objects are required, but not really used, in the code. If you construct a new object every time you just need an empty placeholder, for an object you don't really use, that beats the point of this whole concept.

Answer (score 11):

I assume that (at least now 5 years later) *empty dictionary* really means *empty **read-only** dictionary*. This structure is just as useful as an empty enumerable sequence. For instance you might have a configuration type that has a dictionary property (think JSON) that cannot be modified once it has been configured:

```
public class MyConfiguration
{
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

However, what if the property is never configured? Then `MyProperty` is `null`. A good solution to avoiding an unexpected `NullReferenceException` is to initialize the property with an empty dictionary:

```
public class MyConfiguration
{
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> MyProperty { get; set; }
        = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

The downside is that each allocation of `MyConfiguration` requires an allocation of an empty dictionary. To avoid this you need something similar to `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`, i.e. a cached empty read-only dictionary.

There are two ways to achieve this. The first is to take a dependency on [System.Collections.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/). An `ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implementes `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and it has an `Empty` field that you can use:

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> empty = ImmutableDictionary<string, string>.Empty;
```

Or you can implement your own empty read-only dictionary similar to `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` and `Array.Empty<T>()`. Notice how the empty value is no longer a field and that the class is not generic. Instead it is a generic method. This requires two classes.

The first class is "hidden" and can be internal:

```
internal static class EmptyReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> Instance
        = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
}
```

The second class uses the first class but hides it behind the `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface:

```
public static class ReadOnlyDictionary
{
    public static IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> Empty<TKey, TValue>()
        => EmptyReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Instance;
}
```

Usage:

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> empty = ReadOnlyDictionary.Empty<string, string>();
```

For both solutions there will only be a single empty dictionary instance for each distinct combination of `TKey` and `TValue`.

Comment: Great explanation. I would add, if you already went to such an extent, it would be more appropriate to implement the `IReadOnlyDictionary` with an `Empty` property/method and not to reuse `new Dictionary()` in order to prevent addition of elements to that static instance (which was supposed to be empty throughout its lifetime) using a simple casting to `Dictionary` first (since it was created that way). For example `((Dictionary<K,V>)EmptyReadOnlyDictionary.Instance).Add(k, v)` would spoil the emptyness, obviously.

Comment: Even doing something like this would have the same effect `((Dictionary<TKey, TValue>)ReadOnlyDictionary.Empty()).Add(key, value)`

Answer (score 6):

In .NET 8 preview it is possible to create an empty `Dictionary` by:

```cs
ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Empty;
```

This way uses no memory and is faster than initiating it with the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 12 you can create an empty dictionary this way:

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> dict = [];
```

Answer (score -1):

When the key and value have the same type (e.g.: string):

```
Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToDictionary(x=>x, x=>x)
```

Comment: How is this better than new Dictionnary<string,string>() ?

Comment: This is instantiating a new Dictionary each time you call it. Enumerable.Empty is an immutable structure, but ToDictionary() will create a fresh new Dictionary from it, which you don't want. You want an immutable empty dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

```
Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<string, object>>().ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.

Comment: Same comment as for the @Bill Stanton's answer. This is instantiating a new Dictionary each time you call it. Enumerable.Empty is an immutable structure, but ToDictionary() will create a fresh new Dictionary from it, which you don't want. You want an immutable empty dictionary.

Comment: you helped me :D