# How to use Contains() function if field value is null in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on a project where I use `Linq` for fetching data. Now I have a scenario where I have to check field value contains given string for that I use `Contains()` function.

Everything works fine, But when any of the field is `null` then it creates a problem.

```
personData = personData.Where(x => x.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(q.ToLower()) || x.LastName.ToLower().Contains(q.ToLower())).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Here when FirstName or LastName field have a null value it throw an error.

So, how can I overcome from this problem ?

Comment: Add a clause checking if `x.FirstName` is null..?

Comment: what version of c# are you using? if c#6 then null-conditional is an option.

Comment: I am using C# 4.5 @Nkosi

Comment: What if **q** is null? How do you handle that?

Comment: @stomy, q is parameter to function so we can first check if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(q)) {}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must check first if required values are `null`, Try using the [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)...

```
personData = personData.Where(x => ((x.FirstName.ToLower() ?? "").Contains(q.ToLower())) ||  ((x.LastName.ToLower() ?? "").Contains(q.ToLower()))).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: It throw error "Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string'  and 'bool'" @RahulHendawe

Comment: Great! it is an better way to handle such situation where if you get any `null` value then those values were replaced by _blank value :)

Answer (score 8):

Please try this

```
personData = personData.Where(x => (x.FirstName != null && x.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(q.ToLower())) ||  (x.LastName != null && x.LastName.ToLower().Contains(q.ToLower()))).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: Great to help you. :)

Comment: use named method instead of long lambda. `private static bool Filter(string input, string search) {....}` and then use it in Where. `personData.Where(x => Filter(x, q))` @Jigarb1992

Comment: please post an answer @M.kazemAkhgary

Answer (score 7):

Use following approach: `x.FirstName?.Contains(substring) ?? false`

Since C# 6 you can use null-conditional operators, that simplifies some queries greatly. You can read more about this topic [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What about using a simple string extension like the following:

```
public static string AsNotNull(this string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        return string.Empty;

    return value;
}
```

And then use it like:

```
x.FirstName.AsNotNull()
```

Comment: Likewise, to avoid `null` when you expect a list, you can add a 2nd extension as overload from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3088169/1016343) answer. Then, use it in the same way, i.e. `.Select(x => x).AsNotNull().ToList();`. With both extensions, one for strings, one for enumerables, you are well armed!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should prevent ability to add null FirstName or LastName at the beggining. This kind of row seems unuseful.

Comment: this is good suggestion. because if both FirstName and LastName could be null then whats the point of having names?  I suggest put `""` instead of null if FirstName or LastName has to be empty

Comment: the code I have written in my question is just for example in actual there may be any field/s.