# Null coalescing operator IList, Array, Enumerable.Empty in foreach

Tags: c#, .net, collections, null-coalescing-operator

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088147/why-does-net-foreach-loop-throw-nullrefexception-when-collection-is-null) I found the following:

```
int[] array = null;

foreach (int i in array ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>())  
{  
    System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", i));  
}
```

and

```
int[] returnArray = Do.Something() ?? new int[] {};
```

and

```
... ?? new int[0]
```

In a `NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler` I wanted to apply the `Enumerable.Empty` like so:

```
foreach (DrawingPoint drawingPoint in e.OldItems ?? Enumerable.Empty<DrawingPoint>())
    this.RemovePointMarker(drawingPoint);
```

*Note:* `OldItems` *is of the type* `IList`

And it gives me:

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.IList' and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DrawingPoint>`

However

```
foreach (DrawingPoint drawingPoint in e.OldItems ?? new int[0])
```

and

```
foreach (DrawingPoint drawingPoint in e.OldItems ?? new int[] {})
```

works just fine.

Why is that?
Why does `IList ?? T[]` work but `IList ?? IEnumerable<T>` doesn't?

Comment: `T[]` **is** an `IList<T>`, but there is no guarantee that your object that implements `IEnumerable<T>` implements `IList<T>`. You will have to cast your `IList<T>` object to `IEnumerable<T>` to use it with `?? Enumerable.Empty<T>`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When using this expression:

```
a ?? b
```

Then `b` either must be the same type as `a`, or it must be implicitly castable to that type, which with references means that it has to implement or inherit from whatever type `a` is.

These work:

```
SomethingThatIsIListOfT ?? new T[0]
SomethingThatIsIListOfT ?? new T[] { }
```

because `T[]` **is** an `IList<T>`, the array type implements that interface.

However, this won't work:

```
SomethingThatIsIListOfT ?? SomethingThatImplementsIEnumerableOfT
```

because the type of the expression will be the `a` type, and the compiler is obviously unable to guarantee that `SomethingThatImplementsIEnumerableOfT` also implements `IList<T>`.

You're going to have to cast one of the two sides so that you have compatible types:

```
(IEnumerable<T>)SomethingThatIsIListOfT ?? SomethingThatImplementsIEnumerableOfT
```

Now the type of the expression is `IEnumerable<T>` and the `??` operator can do its thing.

---

The "type of the expression will be the type of `a`" is a bit simplified, the full text from the specification is as follows:

---

The type of the expression `a ?? b` depends on which implicit conversions are available on the operands. In order of preference, the type of `a ?? b` is `A0`, `A`, or `B`, where `A` is the type of a (provided that `a` has a type), `B` is the type of `b` (provided that `b` has a type), and `A0` is the underlying type of `A` if `A` is a nullable type, or `A` otherwise. Specifically, `a ?? b` is processed as follows:

- If `A` exists and is not a nullable type or a reference type, a compile-time error occurs.
- If `b` is a dynamic expression, the result type is dynamic. At runtime, `a` is first evaluated. If `a` is not `null`, `a` is converted to a dynamic type, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, `b` is evaluated, and the outcome becomes the result.
- Otherwise, if `A` exists and is a nullable type and an implicit conversion exists from `b` to `A0`, the result type is `A0`. At runtime, `a` is first evaluated. If `a` is not `null`, `a` is unwrapped to type `A0`, and it becomes the result. Otherwise, `b` is evaluated and converted to type `A0`, and it becomes the result.
- Otherwise, if `A` exists and an implicit conversion exists from `b` to `A`, the result type is `A`. At runtime, `a` is first evaluated. If `a` is not null, `a` becomes the result. Otherwise, `b` is evaluated and converted to type `A`, and it becomes the result.
- Otherwise, if `b` has a type `B` and an implicit conversion exists from `a` to `B`, the result type is `B`. At runtime, `a` is first evaluated. If `a` is not `null`, `a` is unwrapped to type `A0` (if `A` exists and is nullable) and converted to type `B`, and it becomes the result. Otherwise, `b` is evaluated and becomes the result.
- Otherwise, `a` and `b` are incompatible, and a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: Thank you. In the [.NET Documentation on the Array Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.7.2) you can see that it implements `System.Collections.IList`. Is there in equivalent for `Enumerable.Empty<T>` for `IList`?

Comment: Other than `new T[0]`, I don't know of any, there could be something that I don't know about of course.

Comment: Either `new T[]` or `new List<T>()` should do the trick, as @LasseVågsætherKarlsen said

Comment: @IDarkCoder There is [Array.Empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.empty?view=netframework-4.7.2) which is often preferable over `new T[0]` because the latter will always construct a new array instance, whereas Array.Empty reuses the same.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for! However I'm limited to .Net 4.5.2 so I can't use that yet, since its 4.6+ :(

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it determines the type of result by the firs member which in your case is *IList*. The first case works because an array implements *IList*. With *IEnumerable* it's not true.

It's just my speculation, as there are no details [in the documentation for ?? operator online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).

**UPD.** As it pointed out in accepted question, there are a lot more details on the topic in C# Specification ([ECMA](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) or [on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/README.md))

Comment: The C# specification has explicit details, I've included it in my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the non-generic `System.Collections.IList` together with the generic `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>`, as the operands of the `??` operator. Since neither interface inherits the other, that will not work.

I suggest you do:

```
foreach (DrawingPoint drawingPoint in e.OldItems ?? Array.Empty<DrawingPoint>())
  ...
```

instead. This will work because any `Array` is a non-generic `IList`. (One-dimensional zero-indexed arrays are *also* generic `IList<>` at the same time, by the way.)

The "common" type picked by `??` will be non-generic `IList` in that case.

`Array.Empty<T>()` has the advantage of reusing the same instance every time it is called with the same type parameter `T`.

In general, I would avoid using non-generic `IList`. Note that there exists an invisible explicit cast from `object` to `DrawingPoint` in the `foreach` code you have (also with my suggestion above). That is something that will only be checked at run-time. If the `IList` contains other objects than `DrawingPoint`, it blows up with an exception. If you can use the more type-safe `IList<>`, then the types can be checked already as you type your code.

---

I see a comment by ckuri (to another answer in the thread) that already suggested `Array.Empty<>`. Since you do not have the relevant .NET version (according to comments there), maybe you should just do something like:

```
public static class EmptyArray<TElement>
{
  public static readonly TElement[] Value = new TElement[] { };
}
```

or just:

```
public static class EmptyArray<TElement>
{
  public static readonly TElement[] Value = { };
}
```

then:

```
foreach (DrawingPoint drawingPoint in e.OldItems ?? EmptyArray<DrawingPoint>.Value)
  ...
```

Just like the `Array.Empty<>()` method, this will ensure we reuse the same empty array each time.

---

One final suggesting is forcing the `IList` to be generic by the `Cast<>()` extension method; then you can use `Enumerable.Empty<>()`:

```
foreach (var drawingPoint in
  e.OldItems?.Cast<DrawingPoint> ?? Enumerable.Empty<DrawingPoint>()
  )
  ...
```

Note the use of `?.` and the fact that we can use `var` now.

Comment: I thought about creating a singleton like however I figured that int[0] will work until we get .NET 4.6... regarding the `IList`, I can't - without putting too much work into it which isn't worth it here - change the type of that collection because it's part of the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler` of `ObservableCollection<T>`. Although I'm unsure why the didn't use `IList<T>` in this case, since the collection is generic.